# Combine rewriting and redirection rules in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, rewrite, apache2

I have [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) configurations in Apache which used to use the RewriteEngine to do some URL corrections and finally pass control to one (or more, using [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)) Zope/Plone instances.

Now, what I found about doing [load balancing with Plone](https://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/front-end/apache.html#load-balanced-apache-virtual-host-configuration), mentioned the use of [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) / [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) for this final step, and so I considered to use [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for some of my URL corrections. I *can't* [get rid of RewriteRules entirely](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html) because I have a few transformations which include reading a query string variable, and this is possible using [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) only, right?

If I'm informed right, the RewriteEngine processing comes first, and the result (unless pointing out of the context, e.g. using a `[P]` [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)) is then tackled by [normal redirection](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and finally ProxyPass.

Now I wonder whether I should use `Redirect` at all, as long as I still need the RewriteEngine as well.

- Is there any performance gain, under these circumstances?
- What about RedirectMatch, which uses regular expressions as well?

Comment: you can put an example so we can and the output needed

Comment: Well, it's not about _knowing how_ to use `Redirect` instead of `RewriteRule`; the question is: _should I use `Redirect` at all_ while still needing a few RewriteRules? (e.g. because of some transformations which require the use of `RewriteCond`)